# Not able to load ui-view even when the state change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using Angular UI Router. Please find the code below.

**index.html**

```
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/1.0.3/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/AngularControllers/LoginHomeControllers/RouteMainController.js"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/AngularControllers/LoginHomeControllers/LoginController.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ui-view="mainview"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**RouteMainController.js**

```
var app = angular.module("appHome", ['ui.router']);

app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
    $stateProvider
        .state('introduction', {
            url: '/',
            views: {
                'mainview':
                {
                    templateUrl: 'Login.html',
                    controller: 'ctrlLogin'
                }
            }
        })
        .state('login', {
            url: '/login',
            views: {
                'mainview':
                {
                    templateUrl: 'Login.html',
                    controller: 'ctrlLogin'
                }
            }
        })
        .state('home', {
            url: '/home',
            views: {
                'mainview':
                {
                    templateUrl: 'Home.html',
                }
            }
        })
        .state('home.requestsummary', {
            url: '/requestsummary',
            views: {
                'homedetailview':
                {
                    templateUrl: 'Test1.html',
                }
            }
        })
        .state('home.requestsummary.requestdetail', {
            url: '/requestdetail',
            views: {
                'homedetailview':
                {
                    template: "'<h3>Foo</h3>'"
                }
            }
        })
});
```

**Login.html**

```
<div>
    <button id="btnAdd" type="submit"  ng-click="Login()">Login</button>
</div>
```

**LoginController.js**

```
var myApp = angular.module('appHome');
myApp.controller("ctrlLogin", ['$scope', '$location', function ($scope, $location) {
    $scope.Login = function () {
        window.location.href = '#!home/requestsummary';       
    }
}]);
```

**Home.html**

```
<!--Sample Code for displaying Menu Tab and corresponding link-->
<li>
    <a href="#">Employees <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu sub-menu">
        <li><a ui-sref=".employeeadd">Add Employee Record</a></li>       
    </ul>
</li>

<div ui-view="homedetailview"></div>
```

**Test1.html**

```
<a ui-sref=".requestdetail">Hello World</a>
```

I am able to Login successfully and getting the menu tab with "Hello World" Link. I want to display Menu Tab always and change the below text dynamically.

My problem is that whenever I clicked on "Hello World" Link , I am expecting **Foo** to appear in place of "Hello World" Link but it is not working.
Even it is changing states(url) but it is not loading the actual view.

Please help me on this.

Comment: Seems like you want `requestdetail` to be a sibling of `requestsummary` instead of a descendant state

Comment: There can be many links like "Hello World" in requestsummary page and it will open the requestdetail page based on link clicked. But whenever the link is clicked then requestdetail content will override requestsummary content. What is the way out?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a structural problem with your code. The state `requestdetail` is a child state of `home.requestsummary`, and thus, it requires a `ui-view` in the template of `home.requestsummary` state, to which it can bind the HTML.

As per your code, there is no `ui-view` in the `Test1.html`. So, just to be sure that there is no other problem, you can try adding a `ui-view` in `Test1.html`, and change the state config as follows:

```
<!-- Test.html -->
<a ui-sref=".requestdetail">Hello World</a>
<div ui-view></div>

// RouteMainController.js
...
.state('home.requestsummary.requestdetail', {
  url: '/requestdetail',
  template: "'<h3>Foo</h3>'
})
```

After this change, just check if the heading **Foo** appears in the view. If it appears, then everything is fine with your code. Now, the second part is to load the heading **Foo** at the same place where the link of **Hello world** is shown.

To do that, you need to change the view target, because `homedetailview` exists in `Home.html`, which is the parent state of `home.requestsummary`. So, you need to change the state configuration for `home.requestsummary.requestdetail` as follows:

```
// RouteMainController.js
...
.state('home.requestsummary.requestdetail', {
  url: '/requestdetail',
  views: {
    'homedetailview@home': {
      template: "'<h3>Foo</h3>'
    }
  }
})
```

This will absolutely target the `homedetailview` in the state `home`, and your template for `home.requestsummary.requestdetail` will be shown there.

Comment: Yup agree with this was just working on an example to answer here https://next.plnkr.co/edit/IxZW3MjMTgoAdmQy

Comment: @shaunhusain -- Thank you for making a plunker for it. Really helpful!

Comment: No problem thanks for including all the code in the question I just had to take the time to copy and paste then could see what your problem was in action, always easier to solve once you can see it happening.

Comment: Thanks a lot to all of you for explaining me properly